# I can't connect with my database. PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, wamp

I am just a beginner in PHP. And I can't connect my database. Here's my code:

```
<?php
require 'config.php';

class db_class {
    public $host        =db_host;
    public $username    =db_username;
    public $password    =db_password;
    public $db_name =db_name;
    public $conn;
    public $error;

    private function _construct () 
    {
        $this-> conn (); 
    }

    private function connect () {
        $this->conn=new mysqli ($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);
        if ($this->conn) {
            $this-> error ="Fatal Error: Can't connect to lib database" .$this->conn->connect_error;
        return false;
        }
    }

    public function save ($username, $password, $first_name, $middle_name, $last_name, $student_id) 
    {
        $reg = $this->conn->prepare ("INSERT INTO registration (username, password, first_name, middle_name, last_name, student_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)") or die ($this->conn->error);
        $reg->bind_param ("sssss",$username,$password,$first_name,$middle_name,$last_name, $student_id);
        if  ( $reg->execute()) {
            $reg->close();
            $this->conn->close();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

So when I'll click the Submit button, nothing happens. Help please. Thank you!

Comment: Do another `echo $this->conn->error;` after `$reg->execute()` and see if you get an error then

Comment: Might be worth showing us `config.php` as well so we can see if that sets the  `db_host` etc varibales

Comment: The constructor does not so anything! Maybe you should be calling `$this->connect();` in there instead of `$this->conn()`

Comment: You next issue will be the `save` method where the `bind_param()` needs 6 `s` parameters to match the number of parameters in the value list i.e. `$reg->bind_param ("ssssss",....`

Comment: Why do you close the connection once you've saved the data?  Isn't this a case of each instance can only be used once?!

Comment: Also save assumes that the connection has succeeded, it doesn't check prior to the prepare.

Comment: you ask a question and then you go MIA. hm cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @RiggsFolly, your `construct()` function isn't doing anything functional. You have a typo. It should be `__construct()` THe method `conn()` does not exist. You should be calling the `connect()` function. Also the number of placeholders does not match the variables. It should be 6

```
private function __construct() #you have a typo.should be __construct()
    {
        $this->connect(); #call connect() function
    }

$reg->bind_param ("ssssss",$username,$password,$first_name,$middle_name,$last_name, $student_id);#six placeholders for six variables
```

Comment: Ahh I missed the single undescore before `construct()`

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are trying to use mysqli functions and pdo functions.
The rest of you code seems to be just PDO. Try changing your connection string to a pdo approach.

Instead of

```
$this->conn=new mysqli ($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);
```

try

```
$this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
```